# How to check if my hard-drive are on RAID5 or RAID6? - Windows Server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, raid, database, hardware

I'm not sure if a server I own has been setup on RAID or not.

Is there any way to check this within Windows, rather than relying on what the company support tells me?

Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you know if you are using software raid or hardware?

Software: look inside Computer Management --> Disk Management.
The software version only supports Raid 0, 1, and 5

Hardware: Download and install the management software from the vendor to check.
To find the HW vendor look in Device Manager \ SCSI and Raid Controllers

Answer (score 2):

If it's a hosting environment and you're given a VM/VPS, the backend is probably SAN in some form of RAID, and you'd never ever be able to tell that from the OS. If it's private hardware, the answers above are good.

If you're paying someone else to manage your hardware, and you doubt them, why are you paying them? If you want to do some due-diligence, ask for their procedures for handling various types of hardware failure.

Answer (score 1):

If it's hardware RAID, that would depend on the card manufacturer: they might have a utility usable within Windows. If it's software RAID, you should be able to see the status of the disks in the Disk Management plugin to MMC (Right click on my computer and select manage this computer, I believe).

For instance, Adaptec uses [ASM](http://www.adaptec.com/en-us/_common/asm/). But unless the management company has preinstalled these utilities (unlikely) you'll still be left with taking their word for it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the size and number of hard drives in the array? If so, should be a simple matter of looking at Disk Management,seeing how big the reported hard drive(s) are, and doing a little arithmetic.

For example, assuming 6 300GB hard drives:
RAID-0 == ~1676 GB
RAID-10 == ~838 GB
RAID-5 == ~1397 GB
RAID-6 == ~1117 GB

Comment: Not sure that helps this guy out too much, unfortunately. If he doesn't even know if it's RAID, he won't know how many drives he's got. If he can check on the things you're asking about, he can get into the RAID config and check himself.

Comment: this only works if it's a software raid. A hardware raid will only show up as one disk.

Answer (score 0):

"I'm not sure if a server I own has been setup on RAID or not."

Easy calculation

Assume that you server got 4 HDD

Each HDD 100GB

4X100 = 288GB

400 - 30% Raid 5 = 370GB